# How to handle twice to exit features with navigation drawer

Tags: java, android

I am using a simple navigation drawer `Activity` with some fragments. I also implemented doubleBackToExitPressedOnce method under `onBackPressed()`. Where already defined the navigation drawer open and close action for back press. So I modified the code like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    assert drawer != null;

    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Now my problem is when the navigation drawer open, I click on back button for close it first and then I want to exit from app. But every time it will display "Press again to exit". Which is very annoying in some cases. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `drawer` an instance variable in your `Activity`:

```
DrawerLayout drawer;
```

Initialize it in `onCreate()`:

```
drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

And then, something like this should work:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, you made my day. Thanku

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
else if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    }
}, 2000);

}

 else
 {
 super.onBackPressed();
//finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use return statement as given below.

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        assert drawer != null;

        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return;
        }
        else if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```